# Update window display OpenGL/GLUT C++

Tags: c++, events, opengl, graphics, glut

I have a method and I need this method to show the behavior of a virus in a network using GLUT (this is my first time using a graphics library).

I am displaying a number of points and lines that connect them. The program runs fine and it shows the initial state of the network perfectly, but I can't manage to find a way to update the display after I call the method simulate.

The points change color depending on the state of the computer so I need a way to update the display (the network graph) every 3 seconds or something like that. Any ideas?

I have read about using `glutPostRedisplay()` or using `glutIdleFunc()` in some way, but I don't understand how to implement it. Thanks for the help.

Here's my code: (but this only shows the initial state)

```
void Visualizador::visualizar(int cItr, int ios, double vsc, int vcf, double rc, double grc) {

glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize(1280,720);
glutCreateWindow("Network initial state");
glutDisplayFunc(display); //display creates a number of points (computers) and lines (connections)
glutIdleFunc(display);
glutMainLoop();

for (int i = 0; i < cItr; i++) { //cItr: Number of times the state of the network will be updated
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << "State #" << i+1 << " of the network";
    string windowName = oss.str();
    const char* cstr = windowName.c_str();
    simulator.simulate(1, vsc, vcf, rc, grc); //this method can change which point is infected
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutSetWindowTitle(cstr);
    glutMainLoop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of reading the only way I found to accomplish what I was trying to do was erasing code and putting my simulate method inside of the display function. Here is how the code finally worked:

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize(1280,720);
glutCreateWindow("Network initial state");
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutIdleFunc(display);
glutMainLoop();
```

As you may see I leave only the top part of the code. The reason I did this was because glutIdleFunc(display) will be called continuosly so if I change the network state inside the display function (calling simulate) every time glutIdleFunc() calls display the network will change. Also I had to put glutPostRedisplay() at the bottom of glutIdleFunc(). Calling glutPostRedisplay() causes the program to raise a flag that indicates the window needs to be re-drawn or in other words the display needs to be updated.

I include the code for the display despite the fact of having unknown variables because it might help someone:

```
void Visualizador::display() {

if(v->displayCount <= Visualizador::cantIterac) 
{
    int contVertices = 0;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    for (int i = 0; i < Visualizador::v->grafo.cntVrt*2; i += 2) {
        if (Visualizador::v->grafo.obtEst(contVertices) == Grafo::S) {
            glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        }
        else {
            if (Visualizador::v->grafo.obtEst(contVertices) == Grafo::R) {
                glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
            }
            else {
                glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); //red
            }
        }
        glPointSize(5.8);
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2f(arrPos[i], arrPos[i + 1]);
        contVertices++;
    }
    glEnd();

    contVertices = 0;
    glLineWidth(1.6); //Ajusta el ancho de las lineas
    glColor3f(0.2, 1.0, 1.0); //Color blanco
    glBegin(GL_LINES); //empieza a dibujar lineas, cada dos llamadas a la funcion glVertex dibuja una sola linea
    for (int i = 0; i < Visualizador::v->grafo.cntVrt*2; i += 2) {
        int* adyVrt = Visualizador::v->grafo.obtAdy(contVertices);
        for (int j = 0; j < Visualizador::v->grafo.arrVrt[contVertices].lstAdy->obtCntAdy(); j++) {
            glVertex2f(arrPos[i], arrPos[i + 1]);
            glVertex2f(arrPos[adyVrt[j]*2], arrPos[(adyVrt[j]*2) + 1]);
        }
        contVertices++;
    }
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();

    if (v->displayCount < Visualizador::cantIterac)
    {
        Sleep(500);

        v->simulador.simular(1,Visualizador::virusSpreadC, Visualizador::virusCheckFrec, Visualizador::recoveryC, Visualizador::gainResistance);

        ostringstream oss;
        oss << "State #" << v->displayCount+1 << " of the network";
        string windowName = oss.str();
        const char* cstr = windowName.c_str();
        glutSetWindowTitle(cstr);
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
    v->displayCount++;
}
else
{
   glutIdleFunc(NULL);
}
}
```